# FPDF Encoding issues

Tags: php, encoding, fpdf

i wanna encode my pdf file using FPDF so i used this code :

```
require('C:\Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.9/www/PDF/fpdf16/font/makefont/makefont.php');

MakeFont('C:\Windows.old\Windows\Fonts\\comicbd.ttf','cp1250');
```

but it keeps showing me an error :
Error: AFM file not found: cp1250
can't find where the problem comes from ! Any suggestions ?and can anyone tell me what to do to encode my file?

Comment: Why are you using \ and / in a path?

Comment: It's not a problem, using / or \ gives the same results